# How do I install Elementary?

Tags: system, install

Why is it that all the versions of Linux that costs money comes with no install instructions? Some of us have very diminshed mental capacity due to illness so I need things explained very fully and very simply. Now I want to demand my money back as there is no support that comes from any Linux that you pay for. Gives me a bad taste and makes me wonder just how honest all the Linux OS's are just in to take your money, These Linux's might catch a bad review from me should I not get any support after all since I paid I better get all the support I need. Thank you.

Comment: Hi there! There is a very detailed installation guide on the website https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation, it includes everything you need to know to get it up and running. In short: download the .iso file, use etcher to create a bootable USB drive, use that drive to boot up the PC, begin the installation. Also, if you have questions related to free software and the pay-what-you-want model, please give this a read https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2019/09/03/paying-for-linux-distros-and-foss-software-successful-elementary-os/?sh=efccfcb3b3a1

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna copy the comment from the other guy so you can mark this as resolved.

Hi there! There is a very detailed installation guide on the website: https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation, it includes everything you need to know to get it up and running. In short: download the .iso file, use etcher to create a bootable USB drive, use that drive to boot up the PC, begin the installation.

Also, you don't exactly have to pay to use Elementary OS. It works on a "pay-what-you-want" model. But giving a tip to Elementary boosts a lot the motivation of the people who are working on the OS.